# Can different PC's in the same home on different subnets communicate and access data without internet access?

Tags: internet, routing, subnet

I understand basic routing and how a router is needed to communicate between subnets. What I do not understand is if internet access is needed for data to be accessed across subnets.

Thank you for any answers

Comment: Is there a reason why you think it would be necessary?

Comment: I’m new to networking and was reading over different OSI layers, which made me wonder at what point does the transfer of data require internet connectivity

Comment: I suspect that you’re confusing “internet” with “Internet”.  Lowercase “internet” just means having to do with communications between networks. Once at work we had four small networks (a total of about a dozen hosts) set up in one lab. They were connected pair-wise, so I used to quip that we had two independent internets in the room. OSI layers have nothing to do with “the Internet” (uppercase); i.e., the platform that includes global email and the world-wide web.

Comment: @scott - join me in the Dinosour club. Internet with a lower case is now correct according to Websters (see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Internet ). Most people don't know about "an internet" anymore, but I guess its close enough to an Intranet that very few people would need it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can definitely communicate and access each others' shared services via IP address. If you want to use hostnames, you can edit the /etc/hosts file on each machine, or you can set up your own local DNS server, or use something like WINS.

Now, there may be some proprietary software, including embedded software in "Smart Home" / "Internet of Things" devices, that has dependencies on cloud services, but for the most part most software should work fine on a properly configured multiple-subnet IP network with no big-I Internet connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

Think of subnets as two completely different networks. Normally, on a layer 2 level, you could talk to PCs on the same VLAN on the same subnet; however, if you would like to communicate to a PC from one subnet to another, you need to have some type of layer 3 device showing them how to talk. A way for the switch to know how to route the traffic between the VLANs. This is typically done with a router with routes showing how to talk to other subnets. You would need sub-interfaces for each VLAN and your router would then know how to route between them. May need to open up an ACL to allow traffic across the VLANs as well.